# Python - Depth First labyrinth solver

Tags: python, maze

I have a homework in python, where i am supposed to make a "robot" get from the start to the finish, and return the path to the goal. I have the robot searching, but i want the list to just show the path from start to finish. Right now the pathList returns all visited squares.. and also, when it comes to the goal it doesn't stop, just continue with the other nodes.
What am i missing?

```
def find(labyrinth, robotPos, pathList = []):

    frontier = adjacent_passages(labyrinth, robotPos)   
    pathList.append(robotPos)

    if len(frontier) == 1:
        print("Corner")
        return []

    for i in range(0, len(frontier)):
        if frontier[i] == goal:
            pathList.append(frontier[i])
            return pathList

    for i in range(0, len(frontier)):
        if frontier[i] not in pathList:
            pathList.append(frontier[i])
            if (find(labyrinth, frontier[i], pathList) == []):
                pathList.pop()

    return pathList
```

Comment: I think you need more `print` statements in your code.  How do you know that your code is ever reaching the stop condition?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the answer to your problem, but the first thing I notice is you shouldn't be using a list as a default function parameter (`pathList = []`).

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 2):

You're `append`ing `robotPos` to `pathList` without removing it even if the search fails, that's why the list contains all visited positions. I'd suggest to avoid list mutations (append/pop) altogether and instead pass a new value as an argument to the next iteration:

```
if (find(labyrinth, frontier[i], pathList + [frontier[i]]) == [])...
```

Other possible simplifications are:

- drop `robotPos`. Let the current position be the last item of the `path` argument
- use one loop instead of two
- in loops, use `for x in stuff` instead of `for i in range(0, len(stuff))`

Something like

```
def find(path):

    if path[-1] == goal:
        return path

    for new_position in adjacent_positions(path[-1]):
        if new_position not in path:
            found_path = find(path + [new_position])
            if found_path:
                return found_path

    return None
```

Comment: `return None` is unneccessary as `None` is returned by default.